# Which is the right driver to use for an old model Logitech Communicate Webcam?

Tags: logitech-webcam

I have an old model Logitech Communicate Webcam ([image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsb4H.jpg)) and upon returning to the website to get a driver for it, I found that there are several models with slight name variants ([none of which look like my webcam](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/search?q=QuickCam%C2%AE%20Communicate&isSupport=1)).

Which of these drivers is the correct one?

Comment: Well thank you much to the both of you, but those drivers didn't work (probably has something to do with a service pack).

Comment: As Nima noted in his answer. The drivers for that webcam are not compatible with Windows Vista and Windows 7 (and especially not x64). You might be out of luck with this one :( I own a similar Logitech webcam and can relate ;)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/480/3382?hub=1) should work without any problem. Please note that the driver won't work on Windows vista or 7.

Answer (score 1):

According to this image (and this [support matrix](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3428)):

[image][image]

The webcam came with QuickCam. Grab version 8.4.8 here: ftp://ftp.logitech.com/pub/techsupport/quickcam/qc848enu.exe

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to avoid the Logi site revamp. Mine is a QuickCam S5500 I think, I couldnt tell it was so old. If you arent sure roughly for the name of your camera, even if you don't know exact, if you know its a "QuickCam" and its old, google that. Then switch google to pictures tab. I was able to find mine, S5500 I think. Anyway, for drivers files, go here, dont waste your time on their html site: ftp://ftp.logitech.com/pub/techsupport/